# First order ODE and cos(u)/sin(u) idenitity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a first order ODE I must put into a specific form, but this part of the given solution is a mystery to me.

> $\int\frac{\cos u}{\sin u}du = -\int\frac{1}{x}dx$
>
> This can be solved so that $\ln(\sin u) = -\ln(x)+\ln(c) = \ln(c/x)$

I am missing the step for how they achieved the transform:

$$\int\frac{\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}du = \ln(\sin(u))$$

I suspect that Euler's forumla is at work here? Is there a specific resource to show how this step was made explicit?

Comment: $\displaystyle\int\frac{\cos(u)}{\sin(u)}\,\mathrm du=\int\frac{\mathrm d(\sin(u))}{\sin(u)}=\ln\left|\sin(u)\right|+C$

Comment: It's a u-substitution. Let u = sin(x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\int\dfrac{u'(x)}{u(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x=\begin{cases}\ln\big(u(x)\big)+\mathrm C_1, & u(x)\gt0 \\\ln\big(-u(x)\big)+\mathrm C_2, & u(x)\lt0\end{cases}$$